# Is there a way to see what fragments are in a FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout, fragment-backstack

I have the fragment obj as well as the FrameLayout, I could also complete my logic if I can:

Get my fragments containerViewId

OR

See what FrameLayout a fragment is in?

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_frame_layout);
```

it returns the fragment in frame layout

**UPDATE**

to get all fragments that you added in the frame layout (not all frame layouts):

```
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.your_frame_layout, /*your Fragment*/).commit();

        //get all fragments that you added to mFragmentManager
        List<Fragment> fragmentList = mFragmentManager.getFragments();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Ehsan, this returns the last fragment added to the frame layout not all that have been added. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @JoseFlores you should **add** your fragments to fragment manage (don't replace) and you can get a list of all by calling `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()`, it returns a list of `Fragment`.

Comment: The problem with .getFragments() is that it will return fragments in other FrameLayouts as well ...

Comment: @JoseFlores you can do this : `FragmentManager mFragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager()` now you can use `mFragmentManager` on your frame layout. and for get all fragments `mFragmentManager.getFragments()` it returns only the fragments that you added with `mFragmentManager`

Comment: [`getId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getId()) returns the id of the FrameLayout the Fragment was added to, allowing you to filter the list of Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

`(FrameLayout) fragment.getView().getParent()` give it a try. it may give you frame layout that fragment attached to.